# Browser Compatiabilty issue for Html file with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have use   the following html code snippet. While right click on that html file and open with the Operamini, Mozila,Safari, Chrome are working fine but it did not working  in the internet Explorer.

Code snippet[html]:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Simple Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function displaymessage() {
            alert("hai");
        }
        displaymessage();
    </script>
</body>
```

Can you please any one look into this and provide suggestion to resolve the problem . Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rajasekar

Comment: wrap everything in `<html>...</html>`?

Comment: @erickb everything except `DOCTYPE`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1) add html tag to open the page

2) internet explorer blocks "activeX" contents, you should click on the top and unlock them...

Comment: Hi ProGM, Thank you for your answer but i have check the file along with html tag and also i have change the activeX setting through internet option present in the internet explorer but still i have same issue in internet exploerer only . Can you please provide suggesstions ton resolve the problem.

Comment: try go on this site with ie: http://jsfiddle.net/7HaF7/ it's working for me (tested on ie8). Try to check if ie has javascript disabled or security level too high in the options.

Answer (score 0):

By default Internet Explorer restrict running script and ActiveX Controls. If you are not getting any warning, then Go to Tools --> Internet Option ---> Advanced ---> Security ---> Restore Defaults for "**Security level for this zone**".

Hope this may help.